# Can Linux machines joined to active directory update its DNS records?

Tags: active-directory, centos7, windows-dns

Well question is above, but to explain my setup:

- Mikrotik as gateway running DHCP (DNS set to AD)
- Windows 2012 as Active Directory and DNS
- CentOs7 as client

I let CentOs pickup IP from DHCP on mikrotik and then join the machine to AD using this tutorial: https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-join-centos-linux-to-an-active-directory-domain/

But my DNS records are not updating automatically as with windows clients. Using verbose argument while domain joining, I received: Unable to perform DNS Update. DNS update failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER.

I looked around the internet and I could not find clear explanation anywhere. Is it possible to achieve this behavior with current setup?

Comment: It would be a good idea to read the [official documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Windows_Integration_Guide/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put hostname and FQDN to `/etc/hosts` file. After that it worked like a charm.